# Multiple CartThrob installs on one site

Tags: cartthrob, ecommerce, shopping-cart, install

Is it possible to have more than one installation of CartThrob running on one site?

Reason - I need to have Quotes and Orders stored in different Channels.

Has anyone managed to achieve anything similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end, to solve this requirement of having a Quote Basket and a Buy Basket using a single installation of CartThrob, I got Barrett Newton to write a custom extension.
It seems to work really well so far.....  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer no without using something like MSM.

But CartThrob can easily support multiple channels for products. You can also use categories to help seperate orders from quotes.

Comment: OK, so when I create a 'sale' Entry, how do I allocate  it a Category?